# MongoDB suddenly missing / data not found

Tags: mongodb, digital-ocean

Our MongoDB database in Digital Ocean suddenly went missing. When I run `mongod`, it says:

```
MongoDB starting : pid=27161 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=unifyhub-db
2017-01-07T17:36:06.617+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.11
2017-01-07T17:36:06.617+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 48f8b49dc30cc2485c6c1f3db31b723258fcbf39
2017-01-07T17:36:06.617+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-65-215-98 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2017-01-07T17:36:06.617+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-01-07T17:36:06.617+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-01-07T17:36:06.676+0800 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2017-01-07T17:36:06.677+0800 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2017-01-07T17:36:06.677+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2017-01-07T17:36:06.677+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Do you have any idea what happen here? We actually didn't do anything, we just found out that the whole application was not working because the database can't be found.

Comment: when you ran mongod previously, did you specify a different path? with the `--dbpath` param?

Comment: also, i note `Address already in use for socket` - looks like mongod is already running. Try `sudo service mongod stop` then try running mongod again

Comment: Also do `ps aux | grep mongo` and edit it into your question in a preformatted block, so we can see what mongo things are running presently please.

Comment: Have you tried `mongo` and connecting to the instance that may already be running?

Comment: I have the exact same problem; we paused development for a month till now, I tried to run the application yesterday and found it is down (we didn't touch it since a month), I logged into the server and found all MongoDB data lost for both installed applications!! and because I keep the last 5 backups only, all of them are empty too. I have no idea what is happening, whether it is related to DigitalOcean or MongoDB, maybe some configurations change with the start of the new year!!

Comment: Same problem here. DigitalOcean is unsecure, don't use it for sensitive data.

Answer (score 4):

**I think you were hijacked!**

according to http://thehackernews.com/2017/01/secure-mongodb-database.html and http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/55018/cyber-crime/mongodb-hacked.html there is a hacker targeting the opened MongoDB databases, and asks for ransom to return your data back.

I faced the exact same problem as yours. I thought it is something related to digital-ocean but after reading those posts, I checked my server and it is confirmed that it was hijacked.

I opened a mongo shell

```
mongo;
```

listed the databases

```
show dbs;
```

found a database called `READ1` I checked it and found a collection with only one record, a message from the hijacker

```
use READ1;
show collections; // found a collection called info
db.info.find()
```

found this document:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5877674456ae6684507ac017"), "mail" :
>   "ha******@si*****.org", "text" : "SEND 0.1 BTC TO THIS ADDRESS *****
>   AND CONTACT THIS EMAIL WITH IP OF YOUR SERVER TO RECOVER YOUR DATABASE
>   !" }

unfortunately, I didn't check the server since a while and I only keep the last five backups, so I lost my data. But luckily we are still in development mode and we don't have sensitive data.

anyway, I found my `Mongodb` version (2.4.10 Tokumx distribution) allows remote access by default. I tried the following from my local machine and it is surprisingly connected!!

```
mongo server-ip:27017/database-name
```

Finally, I made the following steps to disable the remote access

```
ps aux | grep mongo //found path of the configuration file (/etc/tokumx.conf)
```

then as described [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/enabling-and-disabling-remote-access-to-a-mongodb-server/), I used vim to append the line `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` to the configuration files
then restarted my tokumx service (mongodb in your case)

```
sudo service tokumx restart
```

Now remote access is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your config file is loaded by explicitly calling it when running mongod:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

And in your /etc/mongod.conf file make sure you have

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Now after restarting with this config file, like Ahmed ElBayaa says (I could not comment because of low reputation), try from a remote machine to connect using:

```
mongo server-ip:27017/
```

If all is configured correctly this connection should be refused!